# SearchResultItem IndexField Attribute returning null value

Tags: solr

```c#
public class IndexedItem : SearchResultItem
{
    [IndexField("productname")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

Solr has the data, SearchResultItem Document fields having the value for productname. But, its not mapping to the ProductName property.

This is not a computed field. Normal string type field

I am using sitecore 9.3 , Solr 7

Comment: what is your "productname" field name in sitecore template and also in solr as well?

Comment: sitecore : ProductName , solr : productname_s.      I have tried with [IndexField("productname_s")] as well. still values are not mapping

Comment: As per the compatibility table, Sitecore 9.3 supports Solr 8.1.1 - https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897, but you are using Solr 7 that might be an issue.

Comment: @Mahesh Can you check the query that is getting built while you perform your search From Search.log? and then use the same query in solr and check whether you are getting results? 
Else it might be compatibility issue mentioned by Gaurav